# repeater asp.net issue vb

Tags: asp.net, repeater

i tried to implement asp.net repeater to show all my table attribut in my database

```
 Protected Function Setable(ByVal name As String) As DataTable
        conn.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(1) {New DataColumn("ID", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("attribut", GetType(String))})
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Try

            mycommand = New SqlCommand("select column_name,* from information_schema.columns where table_name = '" & name & "' order by ordinal_position", conn)
            rdrVsd = mycommand.ExecuteReader()
            Do While rdrVsd.Read()
                dt.Rows.Add(i, rdrVsd.Item("column_name"))
                i += 1
            Loop
            rdrVsd.Close()
            conn.Close()
            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            rdrVsd.Close()
            conn.Close()
            Return dt

        End Try
    End Function
```

with this datable returned i tried to do a databinding

```
        Repeater1.Visible = True
        Repeater1.DataSource = Setable(list.Item(i))
        Repeater1.DataBind()
```

which list.Item(i) the name of the table 
but i didn't find a solution to show all my table i only get the first table

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="tblContacts" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
             table                                                                                                                                                                                               

               </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("attribut") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

any idea please

Comment: Where is `Repeater1`? inside another repeater?

Comment: Can you please write clear instructions what you want to do? Still we are not sure what you want to do?

Comment: i want to show each table with its attribut so when i do  Repeater1.DataSource = Setable(list.Item(i))it generate the table i with its attribut when i do Repeater1.DataSource = Setable(list.Item(i+1)) it generate only the first instruction the table i not i+1

Comment: From where are you getting "i"?

Comment: no this is an example in my code i get the name of my table then i pass this name as argument to my function setable() to get all attribute of the table for exemple i pass the table name client and all its attribute can be found after this instruction i would like to show the attribute for two table "client" and "order " only the first table will appear

Comment: You have to combine ALL of your expected results from `Setable` into a single List or collection, and set the DataSource only once. Setting the DataSource repeatedly will not give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to display the entire list of attributes through the `Repeater`. If so, you will want to set the datasource to the entire collection instead of a single item in the collection.

```
Repeater1.DataSource = dt
```

or

```
Repeater1.DataSource = list
```

are the solutions I think you're looking for. The `Repeater` will take the entire collection and generate a new row of markup for each item in the `List` or `DataTable`

Comment: Give it a whirl with setting the DataSource to the entire DataTable/List. That will display each 'attribut' value from the database. 

Or are you looking to set the datasource to display multiple calls to `Setable`? If that's the case, you'll want to modify your database call to get all of the information you need in one swoop, or to join all of the information into a single collection before you set the DataSource.

Comment: i tried to do multiple call to setable but i also get only the first response